# Readonly fileds in Odoo form view

Tags: odoo, readonly, group, access-rights, record-rules

I built a module in Odoo for invoicing where project managers can approve or reject invoices.

I'm trying to create new access rights and record rules for group project manager so that when project manager logs in, the form view fields are readonly for them so that they can't edit it. They can still access the page when the invoices are in awaiting approval state and have ability to click on buttons but can't edit any fields.

```
record id="record_rule_project_manager_readonly" model="ir.rule"
    ​field name="name">Project Manager Readonly      
    ​field name="model_id" ref="model_vendor_bill"      
    ​field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_project_manager'))]"     
    ​field name="perm_read" eval="1"       
    ​field name="perm_write" eval="0"      
    ​field name="perm_create" eval="0"      
    ​field name="perm_unlink" eval="0"      
    ​field name="domain_force">[('state', '!=', 'awaiting_approval')
 record
```

When I go to the page logged in as project manager, I can't access the page. I get this message:

Due to security restrictions, you are not allowed to access 'Vendor Bill' (vendor.bill) records. Records: vendor.bill,2 (id=2) User: Boris Veselov (id=41) This restriction is due to the following rules: - Project Manager Readonly Contact your administrator to request access if necessary.
What can I do to change anything in the code or anyway to bypass it?

I know I can put an attribute with as tate like this to each field: `attrs="{'readonly': [('state', '=', 'awaiting_approval')]}"/>`

But what is the right way to do it according to a specific group?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by creating a compute field.

```py
@api.depends('pmgr_emp_id')
def _compute_is_project_manager(self):
    for record in self:
        is_pm = self.env.user.has_group('AP.group_project_manager') 
        record.is_project_manager = is_pm
```

And adding this to XML for view fields:

```
attrs="{'readonly': [('is_project_manager', '=', True)]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use compute field for the `read-only` of the record, for example:

`make_readonly = fields.Boolean(compute="_make_readonly")`

```py
@api.depends("<field_to_depend>")
    def _make_readonly(self):
        for rec in self:
           # Do you logic code here
```

Then override function method `fields_view_get()`

```py
@api.model
    def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type="form", toolbar=False, submenu=False):
        result = super(Model, self).fields_view_get(view_id, view_type, toolbar, submenu)
        doc = etree.XML(result["arch"])
        if view_type == "form":
            for node in doc.xpath("//field"):
                node_values = node.get("modifiers")
                if node_values:
                    modifiers = json.loads(node_values)
                    modifiers["readonly"] = [("make_readonly", "=", True)]
                    node.set("modifiers", json.dumps(modifiers))

            result["arch"] = etree.tostring(doc, encoding="unicode")

        return result
```

Set on Form View to make this form read-only when `make_readonly = True`